# Instagram Follower Count Display With Punctuation

Tags: php, instagram, counter, instagram-api

I'm currently using this script to get my Instagram follower count:

```html
<?php $instagram="https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/31087586/?access_token=31087586.bf7a21a.5af0d01b2ff1472c8d0a077824990111" ; $instagram_follows=j son_decode(file_get_contents($instagram))->data->counts->followed_by; echo $instagram_follows; ?>
```

Unfortunately, it displays just as a string of numbers (i.e. "12345") and I'd like it to display in the format of "12,345K" instead.

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
$instagram_follows = number_format(instagram_follows);

echo $instagram_follows;
```

or simply

```
echo number_format($instagram_follows);
```

Also there is an error in your code where it says `j son`

This will work

```
<?php
 $instagram="https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/31087586/?access_token=31087586.bf7a21a.5af0d01b2ff1472c8d0a077824990111" ;
 $instagram_follows=json_decode(file_get_contents($instagram))->data->counts->followed_by; echo number_format($instagram_follows) . "K"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove any credentials before post anything!
The value is int so you can use `number_format()`

```
$instagram = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/XXXXXXXXX/?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" ;
$instagram_follow = json_decode(file_get_contents($instagram))->data->counts->followed_by;
$instagram_follows = number_format($instagram_follow, 0, '', ',').'K';
echo $instagram_follows;
```